# IBM 2005-16B switch console cable

Tags: linux, storage-area-network, ibm, console, cable

I have an IBM 2005-16B switch, and it has a male serial connector on it, and I want to use that to configure the device.

I also have a usb to male serial cable, and I have recently created a null-modem cable based on [This](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/bmet/images/e/e0/800px-D9_Null_Modem_Wiring.png/revision/latest?cb=20110627235022) pinout.

I connected all up, used linux cu command with 9600 baud rate (I also had to chmod 666 /dev/ttyUsb0) and I didn't get anything on the console output. (Also tried putty on windows, same results).

Do I have to use some other cable, or my switch is basicly broken?

Comment: What does the IBM documentation say?

Comment: To use their included cable, wich apparently I don't have. In the meantime I figured out the ip address of the switch by disassembling the whole thing , and pulled out it's cf card and the ip address was written in the hosts file. Now I can use a version 6 of javaws to get to a log in screen, but the password is not the default one... So I am back at it again, I need a console cable to reset the passwords.

Comment: What I was getting at is does the IBM documentation have any information about how to make a cable?

Comment: As far as I know it does not have any pinouts or how to diy a cable if you don't have one. "Creating a serial connection Before you can begin configuring the switch, you must create a connection by way of the serial port. To create a serial connection to the switch, perform the following steps: 1. Using the provided serial cable, connect a workstation to the serial port on the switch..."